# How in Koa send generated file

Tags: javascript, pdf, stream, koa

I need to make a pdf file with user content and send it back. I chose
**pdfmake**, because then can make a tables.
I use **Koa**.js;

```
router.post('/pdf', koaBody(), async ctx => {
      const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(myFunctionGeneratePDFBody(ctx.request.body));
      doc.pipe(ctx.res, { end: false });
      doc.end();
      ctx.res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=document.pdf",
      });
      ctx.res.end();
    });
```

And get an error

```
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
        at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:572:17)
        at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:567:10)
        at PDFDocument.ondata (_stream_readable.js:666:20)
        at PDFDocument.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at PDFDocument.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
        at PDFDocument.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:486:10)
        at flow (_stream_readable.js:922:34)
        at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:904:3)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

But save in intermediate file and send its work ...

```
router.post('/pdf', koaBody(), async ctx => {
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(generatePDF(ctx.request.body));
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/document.pdf'));
    doc.end();
    doc.on('error', reject);
    doc.on('end', resolve);
  })
    .then(async () => {
      ctx.res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=document.pdf',
      });
      const stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/document.pdf');
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.pipe(ctx.res, { end: false });
        stream.on('error', reject);
        stream.on('end', resolve);
      });
    });
  ctx.res.end();
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution, currently I'm at the same point where I want to generate a pdf with pdfmake with koa.js. Would like to share your solution?

Comment: See my answer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55372300/10606188

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and your question helped me out, and I've figured out the issue: you're ending the response/stream right away, while it isn't completely written yet. The problem is `doc.end()` returns right away, before writing is finished. The trick is to let your doc end the stream when it's finished (so no more `end: false`) and wait for this event, for example using a Promise.

The fixed code looks like this:

```js
router.post('/pdf', koaBody(), async ctx => {
      const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(myFunctionGeneratePDFBody(ctx.request.body));
      doc.pipe(ctx.res);
      doc.end();
      ctx.res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=document.pdf",
      });
      return new Promise(resolve => ctx.res.on('finish', resolve));
    });
```

Comment: 4 years later you resolved my 4 hours headache. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `writeHead`, see https://koajs.com/#response.

Do like this:

```
ctx.attachment('file.pdf');
ctx.type =
  'application/pdf';
const stream = fs.createReadStream(`${process.cwd()}/uploads/file.pdf`);
ctx.ok(stream); // from https://github.com/jeffijoe/koa-respond
```